# Issue in getting bot targets using microsoft latest toolkit with @microsoft/teamsfx package

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, microsoft-teams-js

We have a bot in place that sends notifications to all users who are participants in the meeting. Additionally, we need to retrieve all the meeting participants and list them in the meeting tab app. To accomplish this, we are utilizing the following line of code to fetch the targets that will identify the specific meeting chat and retrieve all the members from it.

[image]

The following code worked well in the past. However, after updating to the latest Teams Toolkit, the **`.installations()`** method was deprecated, and that's when the issue started. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any comprehensive documentation to address this problem.

As of now, the **`targets`** array consistently returns empty, even though the bot is installed in the meeting chat.

I'm aware that using the Graph API also we can obtain participant details  but this is my second option.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

package.json file:

```
   "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-node": "^2.1.0",
    "@microsoft/adaptivecards-tools": "^1.3.2",
    "@microsoft/teamsfx": "^2.3.0",
    "botbuilder": "^4.18.0",
    "botframework-connector": "^4.20.0",
    "restify": "^10.0.0"
},
```

Answer (score -1):

To get bot targets using the latest Microsoft Teams Toolkit with the @microsoft/teamsfx package, you can follow these steps:

1. Install the Microsoft Teams Toolkit extension in Visual Studio or
   the TeamsFx CLI as mentioned in the context.
2. Create a new project using the Teams Toolkit. You can use the
   teamsfx new command in the CLI or follow the steps in the Visual
   Studio extension to create a new project.
3. Once the project is created, navigate to the bot folder in your
   project directory.
4. Open the index.ts or index.js file in the bot folder. This file
   contains the main code for your bot.
5. In the index.ts or index.js file, you can use the TeamsFxSDK.Bot
   class from the @microsoft/teamsfx package to interact with the Teams
   platform and handle bot commands.
6. To get bot targets, you can use the **TeamsFxSDK.Bot.getBotTargets()**
   method. This method returns an array of bot targets that your bot
   can respond to.

Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates how to get bot targets using the TeamsFx SDK:

```
import { TeamsFxSDK } from '@microsoft/teamsfx';

// Get bot targets
const botTargets = TeamsFxSDK.Bot.getBotTargets();

// Log the bot targets
console.log(botTargets);
```

Make sure to replace @microsoft/teamsfx with the correct version of the package you have installed.

By calling the TeamsFxSDK.Bot.getBotTargets() method, you will receive an array of bot targets that your bot can respond to. You can then use this information to handle bot commands and provide appropriate responses.

For more information and detailed documentation on using the TeamsFx SDK and the @microsoft/teamsfx package, you can refer to the [Microsoft Teams platform documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/overview?view=msteams-sdk-js-latest).